# Add New Item in Sharepoint List List

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint

Can anyone help my in a simple way to add a new item in a list.

I can pull date from the list and show it on a page, I need to know how to create a new item. the target here is when the page load a new entry will be uploaded to the list.

please help.

```js
 -- External jquery
$(document).ready(function(){

    $().SPServices({
                operation: "UpdateListItems",
                async: false,
                listName: "SampleList",
                ID: 3,
                valuepairs: [["ID", id],["Title", title]],
                completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                    alert("Completed");
                }
            });
});
```

```html
-- SP library
   <script src="../javascript/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../javascript/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../javascript/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are missing following property in your SPServices call: batchCmd: "New". See: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b7d45ac0-718f-4ff0-b862-884b23b2793e/adding-newitem-using-sp-services?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: It worked! some times something so little makes a big difference. Developer life. Thanks man